# Gathering iPhone 3g status

Tags: iphone

There is a sample code of apple named "reachability" which tells us the network status of the device, wifi or edge/gprs, but I couldn't see any documentation or sample code regarding gathering if the device is on 3g or not while accessing to internet. I also googled, but no hope. Is it possible to do that, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple representatives, this is not currently possible. See [this message](https://devforums.apple.com/message/94640#94640) on the Apple forums (registration as an iPhone developer required).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a server side solution to your problem?  I assume that your app requires a fast internet connection to operate - maybe you could measure latency, packet loss etc on the server side and take appropriate action if the connection is too slow?